# Using concatenated JS with DEBUG = True

Tags: django, django-pipeline

On my staging server I want it to use the concatenated and minified JS (as I want to have it be as similar to the production server as possible). This is also important for cachebusting as opposed to pointing to single files off of cloudfront (where I host my static assets). But I also want to have DEBUG = True so that I can... well.. debug the templates and server responses and whatnot.

Does anyone know a way to do this?